# ¿Alguien me puede decir por que no me abre los ficheros?

Tags: c++

Tengo varias carpetas en un repositorio y en una de ellas tengo el código y tengo otra carpeta que se llama data, donde quiero guardar los ficheros a crear. La cosa es que me salta directamente al primer else y no puede abrir el archivo. Basicamente lo que hace la función es llamar a otras 3 funciones que analizan un vector aleatorio, un numero de veces, y se guardan los resultados en tres ficheros distintos. Pero no llega a abrirse el primer archivo y no se por que. El profesor nos ha proporcionado un makefile y no se si es ese el error pero los archivos deberian crearse en la carpeta data, pero no se abre. Esta es la función.

```
void Experimento (unsigned tini, unsigned tfin, int inc)
{
    size_t contbs, contbb, contbc;
    vector<int> v;
    float totalbb, totalbs, totalbc;
    int n;
    ofstream sal1, sal2, sal3;

    sal1.open("data/salida_BS.txt", std::ios_base::out);
    sal2.open("data/salida_BC.txt", std::ios_base::out);
    sal3.open("data/salida_BB.txt", std::ios_base::out);

    if (sal1.is_open())
    {
        if (sal2.is_open())
        {
            if(sal3.is_open())
            {
                for (unsigned int i = tini; i <= tfin; i+= inc)
                {
                    GenerarVectorOrdenado(v, i);

                    for (unsigned int j = 0; j <= 20*i; j++)
                    {
                        n = Aleatorio(i);
                        BusquedaBinaria(v, n, contbb);
                        BusquedaConCentinela(v, n, contbc);
                        BusquedaSecuencialParada(v, n, contbs);

                        totalbb += contbb;
                        totalbs += contbs;
                        totalbc += contbc;
                    }

                    sal1 << i << " " << totalbs/20*i << endl;
                    sal2 << i << " " << totalbc/20*i << endl;
                    sal3 << i << " " << totalbb/20*i << endl;
                }
                sal3.close();
            }
            else
                cerr << "ERROR AL ABRIR EL FICHERO salida_BB.txt" << endl;

            sal2.close();
        }
        else
            cerr << "ERROR AL ABRIR EL FICHERO salida_BC.txt" << endl;
        sal1.close();
    }
    else
        cerr << "ERROR AL ABRIR EL FICHERO salida_BS.txt" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Pregunta obvia: ¿ Existe el directorio `data` dentro del directorio en el que estás ejecutando tu programa ? ¿ Dicho directorio tiene permisos para que tu usuario pueda crear archivos ?

Comment: @Trauma Sí, es un repositorio de Git con distintas carpetas de cada práctica. Cada carpeta de práctica tiene distintas subcarpetas, la cual data es para guardar ficheros.  En cuanto a lo de los permisos lo desconozco, pero a través de Gnuplot he podido generar dos imágenes jpeg en esa carpeta, entonces entiendo que sí que tiene permisos. Lo he intentado todo pero siempre me salta el error del primer else que no ha podido abrir el fichero.